# HighCharts HighStocks event flag is obscured by chart border

Tags: jquery, highcharts

If you have a data point with an event marker flag on the last date of the chart's date it is extremely difficult to view as it is pushed to the absolute right most edge of the chart.  Is there a way add more room to the chart for this scenario?  Here is some adapted fiddle code from the highstocks website sample demos where the final record in the chart is labeled "A" which illustrates this problem...

$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function(data) {

```
    // Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
        },

        tooltip: {
            style: {
                width: '200px'
            },
            valueDecimals: 4
        },

        yAxis : {
            title : {
                text : 'Exchange rate'
            }
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'USD to EUR',
            data : data,
            id : 'dataseries'
        },
        // the event marker flags
        {
            type : 'flags',
            data : [{
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 25),
                title : 'H',
                text : 'Euro Contained by Channel Resistance'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 28),
                title : 'G',
                text : 'EURUSD: Bulls Clear Path to 1.50 Figure'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 4, 4),
                title : 'F',
                text : 'EURUSD: Rate Decision to End Standstill'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 4, 5),
                title : 'E',
                text : 'EURUSD: Enter Short on Channel Break'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 4, 6),
                title : 'D',
                text : 'Forex: U.S. Non-Farm Payrolls Expand 244K, U.S. Dollar Rally Cut Short By Risk Appetite'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 4, 6),
                title : 'C',
                text : 'US Dollar: Is This the Long-Awaited Recovery or a Temporary Bounce?'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 4, 9),
                title : 'B',
                text : 'EURUSD: Bearish Trend Change on Tap?'
            },
            {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 4, 10),
                title : 'A',
                text : 'Test Flag Falling off the chart'                            
            }],
            onSeries : 'dataseries',
            shape : 'circlepin',
            width : 16
        }]
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately is not possible. Problem about cutting flags is reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/419

Comment: I had some success with `plotOptions.flags.clip = false`, unsure the degree of success but appears to have worked. Last comment on that issue mentions it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works to solve the problem:

```
yAxis : {
            title : {
                text : 'Exchange rate'
            },
            max: someBiggerValue, // set max to little higher as biggest data 
        },
```